# undefined reference compiling taskwarrior on arm chromebook

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, termux, armv8

I tried to build task-2.5.1 on my armv81 chromebook inside a termux session. It didn't work due build dependencies so I installed them then uncompressed and started in a fresh new directory. When I ran `make VERBOSE=1` I got an `undefined reference to __atomic_fetch_add_4` when linking...

```
[ 98%] Linking CXX executable lex
cd /data/data/com.termux/files/home/src/task-2.5.1/src && /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/lex_executable.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/c++  -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wreturn-type -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++  -O3 -DNDEBUG  -rdynamic CMakeFiles/lex_executable.dir/lex.cpp.o  -o lex libtask.a commands/libcommands.a columns/libcolumns.a libtask.a -lgnutls -luuid
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ld: libtask.a(Nibbler.cpp.o): in function `Nibbler::Nibbler(Nibbler const&)':
Nibbler.cpp:(.text+0x8c): undefined reference to `__atomic_fetch_add_4'
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ld: libtask.a(Nibbler.cpp.o): in function `Nibbler::operator=(Nibbler const&)':
Nibbler.cpp:(.text+0xe0): undefined reference to `__atomic_fetch_add_4'
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ld: Nibbler.cpp:(.text+0x104): undefined reference to `__atomic_fetch_add_4'
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ld: libtask.a(Nibbler.cpp.o): in function `Nibbler::~Nibbler()':
Nibbler.cpp:(.text+0x174): undefined reference to `__atomic_fetch_add_4'
clang-8: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/lex_executable.dir/build.make:90: src/lex] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/data/data/com.termux/files/home/src/task-2.5.1'
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:175: src/CMakeFiles/lex_executable.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/data/data/com.termux/files/home/src/task-2.5.1'
make: *** [Makefile:152: all] Error 2
```

I found [this discussion](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-gnu-toolchain/issues/183) about undefined references in arm builds. I tried adding a -latomic to CMakeFiles/task_executable.dir/link.txt but it didn't change the output.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Possibly answers in this thread at github will help? https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/589

Comment: "*it didn't change the output*" - It should at least change the compiler/linker command line. Can you post the error log with `-latomic`?

Comment: I don't have an answer yet but the link from @CiaPan does seem related, thanks. I don't think the output changed as I read it won't in some cases. I'll try to reproduce it soon. I'm still looking for how to a) understand and b) address this so I can successfully link this and move forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to [wbsch](https://github.com/wbsch) in [this issue](https://github.com/GothenburgBitFactory/taskwarrior/issues/2170) (posted just after this one) for the link to the [known fix](https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/tree/master/packages/taskwarrior) which was successful on my machine, removing the three lines from CMakeLists.txt.